# strftime function doesn't retrieve any records from sql database in android

Tags: android, sql, strftime

I am creating an Expense table with 3 fields category(Text), amount(Integer) and date(Date).

```
    String CREATE_EXPENSE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + Constants.EXPENSE_TABLE_NAME + "("
            + Constants.ID_KEY + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + Constants.EXPENSE_CATEGORY + " TEXT,"
            + Constants.EXPENSE_AMOUNT + " INTEGER," + Constants.EXPENSE_DATE + " DATE" +  ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_EXPENSE_TABLE);
```

I am getting the date from user using a DatePicker and saving it to the database as follows:

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(Constants.EXPENSE_DATE, expense.getDate().getTimeInMillis());
```

I want to retrieve expenses of a particular month and for that I use strf()

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select amount from Expense where strftime('%m', date) = '7'", null);
```

However no records are returned.

I tried the same with strf() - year parameter

```
 Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select amount from Expense where strftime('%Y', date) = '2017'", null);
```

Again no records.

What am I doing wrong here. Kindly guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the date value as string format. 
Below are the valid formats for storing a date in the database.

```
YYYY-MM-DD
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
HH:MM
HH:MM:SS
HH:MM:SS.SSS
now
DDDDDDDDDD
```

Comment: Thanks.I modified the table to store date as String.SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();ContentValues values = new ContentValues();SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();String dateOfExpense = dateFormatter.format(expense.getDate().getTime());values.put(Constants.EXPENSE_DATE, dateOfExpense);Now I am able to retrieve records based on Year.However I am not getting any records based on month.This is my query Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select amount from Expense where strftime('%m', date) = '7'", null);

Comment: What is wrong with the month query?Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select amount from Expense where strftime('%m', date) = '7'", null); There are records with the month of August saved in the database

Comment: change it like this `strftime('%m', date) = '07'` because you're storing the value format is `MM` so value is less then 10 prefix with 0